# Using a file list for the make prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I want to be able to read the prerequisites for a makefile from a file list.

The file list looks something like this:

```
/projects/abc/a.v
/projects/abc/b.v
/projects/abc/c.v
```

and the filelist is called source.flist

This filelist is pretty long and I want to simply use this filelist as the prerequisite for one of the targets in the makefile.

Can someone please tell me how this can be achieved.

PS: I am at a beginner level w.r.t. makefiles

Thanks
Sundeep

Comment: This is quite simple, but why is it necessary? Putting a list of known
prerequisites, however long, in a file and then reading it into the
`make` is merely more complicated and fragile that putting the list in the makefile to begin with.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet. Don't know where I could put the definition of the env variable which will be the filelist.

Comment: Our filelists are auto generated and I want to use a this autogenerated filelist everywhere to avoid duplication errors.

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow so please pardon (and educate me) if I am not following certain ettiquettes here

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by converting your filelist into a makefile in another step:

```
# Makefileall:
all: depsfromfile.out
depsfromfile.mk:
    (echo "depsfromfile:"; cat depsfromfile )| sed -e '/^#/d' -e 's/$/ \\/' -e '$s/ \\//' > depsfromfile.mk   # there is a \t at the beginnging of this line!

-include depsfromfile.mk
depsfromfile.out: depsfromfile
    @touch depsfromfile depsfromfile.out
depsfromfile:
    cat $^ > $@.out
    @touch depsfromfile
```

with a file list depsfromfile

```
# depsfromfile
a
b
c
```

The Makefile autogenerates its dependencies from the `depsfromfile` file. The test target uses the `depsfromfile` to produce output.

The `depsfromfile:` target that is autogenerated into `depsfromfile.mk` and included into the Makefile contains the dependencies.

The `depsfromfile.out` target is only regenerated when a dependency of depsfromfile has been changed.

Now you can

```
# echo "test a" > a
# echo "test b" > b
# echo "test c" > c
# make
cat a b c > depsfromfile.out
# make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```